# Can't get Image to load, even though it's added to RootPanel?

Tags: gwt

I want to display an "img" element as a child of a panel. Should we be using the Image widget for this? I'm doing the following:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(80, Style.Unit.PX);
img.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(80, Style.Unit.PX);

// add it to a panel, which eventually gets added to the root panel.
somePanel.add(img);

// set the url
img.setUrl("stuff/test.png");
```

This works fine on FF. When I run the same code in mobile safari, the images never load. I've added a LoadHandler to the Image instance. I can see that on FF, the event callbacks are triggered. But on mobile safari, they're never triggered.

I recall that an Image must be added to the RootPanel in order for it to ever load, but I am indeed doing that. What else could be causing this? I'm sure the png resource is located correctly.

Thanks

Comment: what does dev tool console says??

Comment: Sorry, what's "dev tool console"? I'm running this in a UIWebView on an iphone. I'm printing console statements to a memory log, and I can see none of my callbacks are getting executed.

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap or any similar technology with GWT? Ensure you tag the same in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb: always use absolute URLs, possibly using `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`, `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()` or `GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles()` as a prefix:

```java
img.setUrl(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "stuff/test.png");
```

This is because GWT code runs in an iframe and is loaded from within a subfolder, and browsers differ in behavior on whether to use the host page or the iframe URL to resolve relative URLs.